# How to mock a non-abstract trait method with phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit, traits

I have a trait (that is used by another trait) with a non-abstract method I need to mock, but when I  try to do so I get the error message:

> Trying to configure method `getOfficeDays` which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

This is the code I'm trying to test:

```
trait OfficeDaysTrait {
  public function getOfficeDays(): array {
    // This normally calls the database, that's why I want to mock it in tests
    return [
     [
       'day' => 'mon',
       'openingTime' => '08:00:00',
       'closingTime' => '17:00:00'
     ]
    ];
  }
}

trait EmployeeAttendenceTrait {
  use OfficeDaysTrait;

  public function isLate($today)
  {
     $late = false;
     $officeDays = $this->getOfficeDays();

     // compare logic with today.. whether the employee is late or not

     return $late;
  }
}
```

And this is my test method body:

```
$mock = $this->getMockForTrait(EmployeeAttendenceTrait::class); 

$mock->expects($this->once())
 ->method('getOfficeDays')
 ->will([])
;

$this->assertTrue($mock->isLate());
```

This syntax is based on the example shown in [phpunit's documentation for testing traits](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html)

Why am I getting this error message and how can I mock `getOfficeDays` to be able to test my `isLate` method?

Comment: I've updated the question to focus on the problem, add a reference to the docs, and (hopefully) make it more discoverable for future readers - feel free to make any changes you feel. Great question, well done :).

Comment: Hey @AD7six, You spent huge time to modify the question and given the exact answer with great explanation. Thank you so much. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Methods which have not been mocked cannot have expectations

I'll go into a bit more detail below but this:

```
$mock = $this->getMockForTrait(EmployeeAttendenceTrait::class);
```

Is mocking no methods, as such `$mock` is the equivalent of:

```
class Testing extends PHPUnitsInternalMockStub
{
    use EmployeeAttendenceTrait;
}

$mock = new Testing;
```

---

### Check the error message

The error message reads:

> Trying to configure method getOfficeDays which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

Let's take a look at each possibility (almost in turn)

#### It does not exist

The code *looks* to clearly have a method named `getOfficeDays` - if in doubt using [get_class_methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) would clarify:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SOTest extends TestCase
{

  public function testMethods()
  {
    $mock = $this->getMockForTrait(EmployeeAttendenceTrait::class);
    print_r(get_class_methods($mock));
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
R                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)Array
(
    [0] => __clone
    [1] => expects
    [2] => method
    [3] => __phpunit_setOriginalObject
    [4] => __phpunit_getInvocationMocker
    [5] => __phpunit_hasMatchers
    [6] => __phpunit_verify
    [7] => isLate
    [8] => getOfficeDays
)


Time: 569 ms, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) SOTest::testMethods
This test did not perform any assertions
```

So it's not that.

#### is final

```
public function getOfficeDays(): array {
```

The method signature clearly does not [declare the method as final](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) - so it's not that.

#### or is static

```
public function getOfficeDays(): array {
```

The method signature clearly [is also not static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) - so it's not that either.

#### has not been specified

By logical deduction  this *has* to be the problem - and it's the only one which requires some understanding of using phpunit.

The [docs for getMockForTrait](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html) read (emphasis added):

> The getMockForTrait() method returns a mock object that uses a specified trait. **All abstract methods of the given trait are mocked**. This allows for testing the concrete methods of a trait.

Since none of the trait methods are abstract, no methods are expected to be mocked with the syntax in the question. Looking deeper, the [method signature for getMockForTrait](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4a5367636d1df3b3727ba7d1d226dbdfc5ce5fa0/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L231-L238) has more arguments:

```
    /**
     * Returns a mock object for the specified trait with all abstract methods
     * of the trait mocked. Concrete methods to mock can be specified with the
     * `$mockedMethods` parameter.
     *
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    public function getMockForTrait(
        string $traitName, 
        array $arguments = [], 
        string $mockClassName = '', 
        bool $callOriginalConstructor = true, 
        bool $callOriginalClone = true, 
        bool $callAutoload = true, 
        array $mockedMethods = [], 
        bool $cloneArguments = true): MockObject
```

There is a parameter for specifying explicitly mocked Methods, therefore writing the test like so:

```
class SOTest extends TestCase
{

  public function testMethods()
  {
    $mock = $this->getMockForTrait(
      EmployeeAttendenceTrait::class, 
      [],   # These
      '',   # are
      true, # the
      true, # defaults
      true, #
      ['getOfficeDays']
    );

    $mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('getOfficeDays')
     ->willReturn([]);

    $today = new DateTime(); // or whatever is appropriate
    $this->assertTrue($mock->isLate($today));
  }
}
```

Will generate a valid mock object and allow the test to run.